# Как используя побитовые операции найти максимальное значение данного типа?

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Как используя побитовые операции найти максимальное значение данного типа? Например: `std::uint8_t`, `std::uint16_t`, `std::uint32_t`, `std::uint64_t`.

Comment: size = (1 << (sizeof(type) * 8) ) - 1 вроде так...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов тут же переполнение, разве нет?

Comment: @pavel вроде зависит от типа size. Ну можно еще через type maxVal = -1 сделать. А можно единицу в цикле вдвигать...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов для uint16_t выводит 3

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan А, ну да, надо на 8 умножить же. Туплю, спасибо!

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов C++ не обещает, что байт состоит из восьми бит )

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Пичалько... Ну тогда умножать надо на sizeof (char) :-)

Comment: По хорошему (если сдвиги не обязательное условие) использовать std::numeric_limits<тип>::max()

Comment: я так  написала: https://ideone.com/9LabeG

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, `1 << (sizeof(type) * 8`, The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or **equal** to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Господа, а вас не смущает, что `1 << (sizeof(type) * 8))` - **это просто нуль**? Да и, по-хорошему, компилятор должен предупреждать о некорректности такого действа (VC++ честно предупреждает).

Comment: @Harry, нет, это не нуль, это UB.

Comment: @wololo Де-юре, де-факто компиляторы это в 0 скомпилируют... Ну, сделайте `(1<<sizeof(type)*7)<<sizeof(type)` :)

Comment: @Harry, `(1<<sizeof(type)*7)<<sizeof(type)` - всё ещё UB, потому, что "[...] Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 × 2^E2 **is representable** in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Harry, "Де-юре, де-факто компиляторы это в **0** скомпилируют". Нет. [Пример.](https://ideone.com/Osc3et)

Comment: @wololo Это не одно и то же, вообще-то говоря. https://ideone.com/YxfOzc

Comment: @Harry, то есть Вас не смущает тот факт, что одно и тоже UB-выражение посчитанное во время выполнения не совпадает с тем же самым выражением, но посчитанным во время компиляции? [Пример 2.](https://ideone.com/uTm1JE) И Вы уверены, что свеженькая версия компилятора, которая выйдет, например, завтра, на этапе компиляции не вычислит его также как и во время выполнения?

Comment: @wololo Меня вообще мало что смущает :) Хотя бы потому, что имеется какая вещь, как `numeric_limits` :) А вся наша жизнь учит жить не по закону, а по понятиям :) Что до метода определения - я привел свои варианты в ответе, и там нет предложения о сдвиге на N-е количество бит...

Answer (score 6):

Например, можно проинвертировать 0 для соответствующего типа

```
uint64_t ret = ~uint64_t(0);
uint32_t ret2 = ~uint32_t(0);
```

Но это работает только для беззнаковых типов (про знаковые, как я понимаю, речь не идет).

Answer (score 3):

Для [типов с фиксированной шириной](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (унаследовано из Си) определено побитовое представление (которое на практике и для других целых типов используется). В этом представлении (определив `bitwise_limits<>` класс по аналогии со [`std::numeric_limits<>`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)):

- у наибольшего числа *без знака* все биты выставлены (no padding bits)

  ```
  static constexpr T max() noexcept { return ~T(0); }   // all bits set
  ```
- у наименьшего числа *без знака* все биты нулевые (не выставлены)

  ```
  static constexpr T min() noexcept { return  T(0); }  // all bits clear
  ```
- у наибольшего числа *со знаком* выставлены все биты, за исключением бита под сам знак

  ```
  static constexpr T max() noexcept { // all bits set except sign
    return bitwise_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max() >> 1;
  }
  ```
- у наименьшего числа *со знаком* все биты не выставлены за исключением знака ([дополнительный код](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement))

  ```
  static constexpr T min() noexcept {
    return ~max(); // all bits clear except sign
  }
  ```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/eBUhcS):

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << (int)bitwise_limits<uint8_t>::max() << '\n';
  std::cout << (int)bitwise_limits<uint8_t>::min() << '\n';
  std::cout << (int)bitwise_limits< int8_t>::max() << '\n';
  std::cout << (int)bitwise_limits< int8_t>::min() << '\n';
}
```

#### Результат

```
255
0
127
-128
```

Answer (score 0):

Они все беззнаковые, так что фактически это значение -1, приведенное к данному типу -

```
type(-1)
```

Можно и сдвигами, хотя это медленнее - просто считать, после какого сдвига перестанет расти - что-то типа

```
unsigned int x = 1;
for(;;)
{
    unsigned int y = (x << 1) + 1;
    if (x == y) break;
    x = y;
}
printf("%lx\n",x);
```

P.S. Совет сдвинуть на `sizeof(type)*8` бит и вычесть 1 - это, собственно, мой первый совет, так как `1<<sizeof(type)*8` при 8-битовом байте :) даст просто 0...

Comment: почему-то такой цикл компилятор оптимизировать не сумел(

Comment: @pavel Ну, если записать это все как `constexpr`-функцию, то VC++2017 честно делает `push -1
 push OFFSET ??_C@_04OBABDBEP@?$CFlx?6?$AA@
 call _printf`